# when adding two items in config.xml to show the navigation. Why does It display only one?

Tags: xml, magento

I am working on a project of `magento` where I am trying to list a menu item in the main navigation. In this there is an `observer` per model. What I am tying to do is to add another menu item using the existing observer. For this I created a function:

```
class Color_Observer{
    // Existing function for "colors" menu item.
    public function ListMenuItems(){
        //code here 
    }

    // New function for "composite colors" menu item
    public function MyListMenuItems(){ 
        // 
    }
}
```

and I added following code in `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
      <events>
         <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
            <observers>
               <my_color>
                  <class>my_color/observer</class>
                  <method>ListMenuItems</method>
               </my_color>
               <my_color_val>
                  <class>my_color/observer</class>
                  <method>MyListMenuItems</method>
               </my_color_val>
            </observers>
         </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
      </events>
</frontend>
```

This code is successfully creating the menu for `composite colors` but it replaces the already existing `color` menu.

Can anyone please help me whats going on? I am new to `magento`.

Comment: Try link i hope your problem may be solve.
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/adding-links-to-the-top-menu-in-magento/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  observer type  `<type>singleton</type>`

```
<frontend>
      <events>
         <page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
            <observers>
               <my_color>
                  <class>my_color/observer</class>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <method>ListMenuItems</method>
               </my_color>
               <my_color_val>
                  <class>my_color/observer</class>
                  <type>singleton</type>
                  <method>MyListMenuItems</method>
               </my_color_val>
            </observers>
         </page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before>
      </events>
</frontend>
```